# Extract comma separated values from variable and store them in array in shell script

Tags: shell-script

I have a shell script and a variable that contains numbers separated by comma. The variable would e.g. look like this: 14,7,45,12,13

Now I would like to extract all of those numbers without the commas and store them individually in an array.

How would I go about that?

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this using sed.
I am cutting the commas out and replacing them with spaces and then import them into an array.

```
CUTID=$(echo "$CUTID" | sed 's,\,, ,g')
IDARRAY=($CUTID)
```